# MySQL slow query log logging fast queries

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-slow-query-log

I'm having an issue where MySQL seems to be logging queries in the slow query log that are faster than the time specified. I've configured MySQL to log the following:

```
Server version: 5.1.54-1ubuntu4-log

+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                         |
+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| log_slow_queries    | ON                            |
| long_query_time     | 2.000000                      |
| slow_query_log      | ON                            |
| slow_query_log_file | /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log |
+---------------------+-------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, in my slow query log I can see that it's logging sub-second queries:

```
# Time: 121116 17:09:00
# User@Host: user[user] @ ip-10-x-x-x.ec2.internal [x.x.x.x]
# Query_time: 0.007098  Lock_time: 0.000075 Rows_sent: 50  Rows_examined: 2693
```

I've set the above variable dynamically using 'SET GLOBAL ...', but even before that the long_query_time was set to 1.000000 seconds.

Any idea why MySQL could be logging queries that are faster then what is specified?

Comment: Have you specified `log_queries_not_using_indexes` by any chance?

Comment: Yes! That was it. Thanks for the quick response. If you want to submit an official answer, I'll select it as accepted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html), there's another option that could cause queries to get logged in the slow query log:

[`log_queries_not_using_indexes`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-queries-not-using-indexes)

Comment: Unbelievable. My hosting provider is subpar to say the least.
Thank you for this.